# Node js speed up puppeteer html to pdf

Tags: html, node.js, pdf-generation, puppeteer

I have a node js application that creates dynamic content which I want users to download.

```
static async downloadPDF(res, html, filename) {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });
    
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    
    await page.setContent(html, {
        waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
    })
    
    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
        format: 'A4'
    });
    
    res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".pdf");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    res.send(pdfBuffer);
    
    await browser.close()
}
```

Is there a way to speed up the whole process since it takes about 10 seconds to create a pdf file of size about 100kb?
I read somewhere that I can launch the headless browser once then I will only be creating a new page instead of launching a browser every time I request for the file.
I cannot find out a correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move `page` creation to a util and hoist it to re-use it.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let page;

const getPage = async () => {
  if (page) return page;

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  page = await browser.newPage();

  return page;
};
```

.

```
const getPage = require('./getPage');

static async downloadPDF(res, html, filename) {
    const page = await getPage()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no reason to launch browser every time. You can set Puppeteer to call a new url and get content. Without launching every time, it would be faster.

How to implement this ?  Cut your function into three steps :

1. Create a browser instance. No matter headless or not. If you run app in X environment, you can launch a window, to see what your Puppeteer does.
2. Create a function code, that will do main task in cycle.
3. After block is done, call `await page.goto(url)` ( where "page" is the instance of `browser.newPage()`) and run your function again.

This is one possible solution of function style code :

1. Create a instances :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {'headless' : false });
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setViewport({'width' : 1280, 'height' : 1024 });
```

I have put it in a realtime async function like `(async ()=>{})();`

2. Get data :

Im my case, a set of URLs was in Mongo DB. After getting them, I  ran a cycle :

```
for( const entrie of entries)
{
  const url  = entrie[1];
  const  id = entrie[0];
  
  await get_aplicants_data(page,url,id,collection);
}
```

3. In `get_aplicants_data()`, I had realized a logic according to a loaded page :

```
await page.goto(url);  // Going to url 
//.... code to process page data
```

Also you can load a URL in cycle and then put in your logic.

I hope I have given you some help.